# Webcam video -> to -> Website

Tags: c#, .net, webserver, webcam

I asked a slightly similar question previously but never got a good handle on this specific piece.   Here's the setup:

1. Webserver: I have coded my own webserver.  Works great.   I have no issues here.  It can handle any known mime-type (that I define) and send files accordingly.   It can do so dynamically as well to send information within the responses like date/time, database results etc.  So I need no help here.
2. Webcam code: I have coded a windows control that allows me to select whatever webcam I have hooked up and to view a preview inside the control.  So I need no help here.

Here's where the issue arises.  I want to connect these two components together so I can grab frames and stream them out the web server to viewers who request video.

Reading, I find that I probably want to write some sort of routine that takes regular "snapshots" at 5/10/20/30 frames per second and then, on-the-fly push them to some sort of MPEG routine to convert to MP4 and push the resulting bytes out to the viewer.

Can someone help enlighten me on how to do this?   I don't know what the request should be from the client's end (presumably HTML5) and how to elegantly handle the stream.  Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: In HTML5 you have a video tag. But this only opens the Client's default Video player. You could setup an RTSP/RTP Server with VLC for example and hook this up into a video-link.

Comment: Thanks Fildor but I am still not seeing it.   I understand in HTML5 you're just launching a player to play, say, and MPEG video.  Its the stuff on the server that I am trying to figure out.   Do I capture snapshots and pipe them into something to conver to mpg?  Thanks!

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If you have like a framerate of 1/min; it may be better to update an image on the server and have the page reload every 60 sec. If there is really video you want to transmit, then you may pretty probably want to go with a streaming solution. So, yes: You will have to encode the images. Most Network-Cameras have built-in encoders for different formats and protocols. MJPEG, MP4 / H.264 ... and protocols like HTTP, RTSP ... USB-Cams tend to not offer such features. In that case you would have to fetch an image-stream or still images and encode a stream.

Comment: Yea, thanks Fildor, for the confirmation.  I am using a webcam not a network camera.  I am looking at a few MMJPEG wrappers that might do it but I gotta say I am a bit green in this area.  I assume I just keep "clicking" the snapshot and push them through the MMJPEG processor and then out to the world somehow.   Thats where I'm sorta stuck.

Comment: Depends on the API of your camera. Some WebCams can push an image to a directory based on a schedule. Some have to be polled. If you must poll it, you may want to use some sort of little program or script. To encode for streaming ... well that's a different story then. Of course MJPEG is the easiest, because - well it's jpegs stuffed together ... Since you tag this C#/.net I can assume we are talking about windows OS here, right? Linux has some neat utilities to frequently poll an image.

Comment: I can also recommend to look for a Raspberry PI - solution for this. For one it is a low power, low cost way to have an always-on-server for this and there maybe already some projects that may support your cam.

Comment: Lol, I don't think I can embed the Raspberry Pi solution into my .NET application that incorporates web cam streaming as part of its use.   But thanks for the suggestion :)  yes, All windows.   So I am trying to figure out that part.  Stuffing JPGs into MJPEG and output a stream...somehow :)